# I connected my web with port 80 and it is connected, but the web shows 'Unable to connect'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Ruby on Rails and AWS server.
I opened 80 port in my instance's security group,  logged in my server through terminal,
and typed

```
  $rvmsudo rails s -p 80
```

And this is the result of the command.

[image]

So I opened my webpage with Safari, but the browser showed 'Unable to Connect'.
I killed other background Rails processes and there was only one that is connected to the port. I can't get the reason the webpage is unable to connect.

Comment: How are you accessing the port? Via a domain, or via the IP? Does AWS care how you connect?

Comment: I'm accessing via the domain. Strangely when stopping the access(ctrl+c) and accessing to the port 3000, it worked well. so it seems it has nothing to do with domain. @EmilKampp

Comment: That sounds like the problem is that the Rails application isn't allowed to bind to port 80. Or more precisely that the Rails app is open for port 80, but the port access isn't forwarded through the network of AWS clusters and firewalls.

Comment: The default port for Rails is 3000 , apache uses the port 80 for example.